# why does onActivityResult() return resultCode=0 when user clicks OK?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Here are the two functions I found from someone else's example.  Seems to work well for me up to the point where resultCode is examined.  Regardless if user presses OK or Cancel, resultCode is zero.  Can you tell me why?  This code exists inside an Activity class that inherits from AppCompatActivity.  I tried adding the call to super.onActivityResult but it doesn't change the behavior in any noticeable way.

**EDIT** The "intent" parameter is always null in onActivityResult.  Only requestCode comes back correct.  Help! Stupid computers... they hate me!

```
public void onClickChooseNotificationSound(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
    this.startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent)
{
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 5)
    {
        Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

        if (uri != null)
        {
            NotificationSound = uri.toString();
        }
        else
        {
            NotificationSound = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions added to your manifest?

Comment: Is that with all the sound chooser activities?

Comment: Ben - I don't know.  What special permissions do I need to do this?

Comment: Shaishav - Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: post your manifiest file here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to have been caused by the *calling* class being declared as single instance in the manifest such as

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    </activity>
```

I removed that to be like

```
 <activity android:name=".MyActivity" />
```

and now it's all good.  Now I need to re-evaluate why I was using singleInstance on all my activities in the first place.